# Excel remaining days count from today until due date minus weekends?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using `=IF([TodayDays]<0,0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),[DueDate],1))` which seems to work, but here's my question. Why on  On some date configurations the larger the total days remaining seems to mess with the calculation and add extra days.

I'm confused so using a start date like 6/16/20, the end date of 7/16/20 equals 23 days total. But when I calculate the days left minus weekends I get 25 days left. How could this be happening?

[Link to my study excel sheet "Days Remaining Minus Weekends"](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhFSazYw9XzujXx4itv1FU9E_nC2)

Any tips or answers would be helpful, thanks!

[Image of my workbook with the issues I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFH71.png)

Comment: ```=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2020;6;16);DATE(2020;7;16);1)``` Result = 23. Count the days on a calendar is the same. Where is the problem?

Comment: Yep, using the Start Date of 6/16/2020 and the Due Date of 7/16/2020, I'm using '=NETWORKDAYS.INTL([Start],[Due],1)' to calculate the days between the start and due date which I get 23 days. Then using '=IF(TotalDays<0,0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),[DueDate],1))', I get 25 days. So I don't know where I'm going wrong. (you should be able to see what I'm trying to do with eh link I provided, maybe that would help?)

Comment: Don't share links to your work book - many won't open a link provided by stranger for obvious reasons. Instead, show us a screen shot that demonstrates your point. Show us the formula you are using along with all of the inputs/outputs.

Comment: Not sure why there's a link option. But, my formula is stated in my question and my response to the initial comment. So is there something that I'm missing from my formula that would be adding days to the remaining days left from today till the due date?

Comment: Today is the 12th not the 16th.  If you put 6/12/2020 in B4 you will get 25, you are missing Today and Monday the 15th when you only look at the 16th

Comment: if we assume that today is 06/12/2020 and [DueDate] is 07/16/2020 than the result 25 is correct, as you can count on a calendar.

Comment: Gotcha so I was doing it correctly. Ok thanks, thinking too hard over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for showing me that I was overthinking this, that I wasn't counting the days until the start date too for in case the start date falls in the future. The formula I was using had been correct all along, using the formula here:
`=IF(D5<0,0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),C5,1))`
This checks firstly **IF** the total days between the range of start & due dates are greater than "0", then secondly using **NETWORKDAYS.INTL** to calculate from today's date with **TODAY()** function and the due date, minus the weekends to return the number of days left until the due date.

[Checking my work, a screenshot of my worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHHzP.png)

Update: To my formula to check if the due date is greater than today, if not then it returns "0" instead of a negative value. My answer: `=IF(C4>TODAY(),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(TODAY(),C4,1),0)`. Just using the first argument of logic to check if the due date is greater than today's date.